# Storing data for comparing two directory structures

Tags: java

I want to compare 2 directory stuctures (only files), so first I'll get some list of files, with this structure: Filename|size 
For ilustration: 
(1):

```
C:\Downloads\100 Java Tips.pdf|1025kB
C:\Downloads\1590599799.rar|1000kB
C:\Downloads\573440.flv|50000kb
C:\Downloads\575492.flv|40000kb
C:\Downloads\avira_antivir_personal_en.exe|15000kB
C:\Downloads\backup-mkyong.com-12-24-2009.tar.gz|2000kB
```

Then I want to compare 2 directory sturctres = I will have two files with list directory structure (see (1)). One file will be reference the second file will be compared.
I have only tree outcomes:
1)ok - file in first structure exist in second structure with same size
2)fail1 - file in first sturcture doesn´t exist in second 
3)fail2 - file in first structure exist in second structure but have diffrent size

My question is, what is best for storing the data what i´ll be comparing?
For example I put the data from file1 to "shelf1" and from file2 to "shelf2".
Question is what the shelf should be? Array, ... 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the same paths (absolute or relative) you could use a hashmap and use the path as the key and the size (or the corresponding `File` object) as the value.

Then loop over the entries of map 1 and check if they exist in map 2 and have the same value (i.e. size).